# Import Processing Serial library into java file

Tags: java, processing, processing-ide

So I have `.pde` file and several `.java` files that are used in a project. I import the library as so into a `.java` file:

```
import processing.serial.*;
```

When I import the Processing serial library in the `.pde` file it works fine, but when I import the Processing serial library into a `.java` file I get this error:

> The package "processing.serial" does not exist. You might be missing a
>   library
>
> Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the
>   sketchbook folder (see the Preferences window).

Do I need to install the library to be able to use it with a `.java` file or is there another solution to import the Processing serial library into a `.java` file?

Comment: How are you editing this file? Are you using the Processing editor?

Comment: yes, I'm using the Processing editor to test my java files in a pde file.

Comment: How are you adding the library to the sketch? What exact steps are you following?

Comment: It works in a pde file, it doesn't work in a java file. I didn't add anything, serial is a library the comes with processing, but only the pde file can import it.

Comment: You need to add the library to your sketch before you can use it. How are you adding the library to your sketch?

Comment: You are correct. found something similar on a processing forum: https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/using-serial-in-custom-library.html

Comment: I was adding the library the same way to the sketch, but once I added it to my .pde file (sketch) it worked in my java file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries don't come automatically included with Processing. You have to add them to your sketch using the `Sketch > Import Library` menu. This is true whether you're in the main sketch file or in a `.java` tab.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/libraries) is a tutorial on using libraries in Processing.

Comment: Yes, but you'll notice when going through Sketch > Import Library, Serial is already there and if you look up Serial in the "Add Library.."  window you won't find the correct library. The serial library is located in the processing folder when downloaded in the modes\java\libraries\serial folder, so it does not need to be downloaded. It does need the import lines in both .pde and .java though.

Comment: @karamazovbros Yes, it's downloaded, but it's not added to the sketch until you go to `Sketch > Import library` and choose the Serial library. This does two things: it adds the library to your classpath, and it adds some import statements at the top. Just adding the import statements isn't enough, you have to add the library first!

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know about the adding the library to the classpath part, I just thought it added the import statements.